How to force two blocks, of 2 x pairs in a div, to stay side-by-side ie. each pair cannot be split?
I'm relatively new to HTML/CSS and Liquid. And I am trying to create and style a couple of custom blocks in a Product Page that will show in the page as 2 x pairs of blocks in one div

I have created this with the code below, and it works well, except for mobile screen where the wrapper forces the 4th block to break onto a new line.
I'm wondering if there is a way to force the pairs of two blocks to stay together, so a pair will be forced down to a new line rather than breaking a pair??
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
<div><p style="
  display: inline-block;
  background: #9b845a;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #9b845a;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bolder;"
<p>Condition
<p style="
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #9b845a;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  color: #232323;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bolder;"
<p>Condition Text pulled from custom Product field</p>
<p style="
  display: inline-block;
  background: #9b845a;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #9b845a;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bolder;"
<p>Size
<p style="
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #9b845a;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  color: #232323;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bolder;"
<p>Size Text pulled from custom Product field</p></div>

Issue: the 4th block is forced down to a new line on Mobile Screens. I'd like to force blocks 1 & 2, and 3 & 4, to stay together so the label and the text do not split?


Hey, thanks @mplungjan. Last question first: :-) trust me to create something new lol. That will just be my lack of knowledge of html. First question: it is just going into Shopify custom liquid block. The code removed between the two lots of  tags is:
<class=”custom-field”> {{ product.metafields.custom.poster_condition | remove: "[" | remove: "]" | remove_first: '"' | remove_last: '"' }}
<class=”custom-field”> {{ product.metafields.custom.size | remove: "[" | remove: "]" | remove: "" | remove_first: '"' | remove_last: '"' }}
This also works, so no problem with these.

Please click [edit], then the button marked [<>] and post a [mcve] with the actual code as seen when you right-click and inspect the HTML

You can wrap in another inline-blocked tag and use white-space:nowrap. I use span since your initial markup was invalid. Note I removed the whitespace between the pair of inline elements to make sure the whitespace did not mess up the display
NOTE: I recommend you extract the CSS from the elements and use classes with a CSS stylesheet


<div>
  <p style="display:inline-block; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="
  display: inline-block;
  background: #9b845a;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #9b845a;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bolder;">Condition</span><span style="
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #9b845a;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
   margin:0;
  color: #232323;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bolder;">Condition Text pulled from custom Product field</span></p>
  <p style="display:inline-block; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="
  display: inline-block;
  background: #9b845a;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #9b845a;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bolder;">Size</span><span style="
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #9b845a;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  color: #232323;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bolder;">Size Text pulled from custom Product field</span></p>
</div>




Thanks @mplungjan. Had to tweak to add the margin-right on first pair, instead of margin-left on second pair, but works. Much appreciated, thanks.
I'll have to do some more reading on 'span'. Cheers

Yeah, I removed the margins when I saw a gap, then realised it was the whitespace between the spans.

You can also use the CSS Flexbox with the flex-wrap and align-content properties. This will allow you to group the pairs and control how they behave when the screen size changes.


<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-content: flex-start;">
    <p style="
      display: inline-block;
      background: #9b845a;
      padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px;
      border-color: #9b845a;
      border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: bolder;">Condition</p>
    <span style="
      display: inline-block;
      background: #ffffff;
      padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px;
      border-color: #9b845a;
      border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px -5px;
      color: #232323;
      text-align: left;
      font-weight: bolder;">Condition Text pulled from custom Product field</span>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-content: flex-start;">
    <p style="
      display: inline-block;
      background: #9b845a;
      padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px;
      border-color: #9b845a;
      border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px 10px;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: bolder;">Size</p>
    <span style="
      display: inline-block;
      background: #ffffff;
      padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px;
      border-color: #9b845a;
      border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
      margin: 0px 0px 5px -5px;
      color: #232323;
      text-align: left;
      font-weight: bolder;">Size Text pulled from custom Product field</span>
  </div>




You should create a few classes in CSS so that the styles do not pollute the markup. These classes also become portable, and can be reused many times.
I also recommend you set a consistent border and padding for all children of the badge. This way, all you need to do it disable or modify parts of the border/padding as needed. This will increase the readability.


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.badge {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.badge div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #9b845a;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 6px;
}

.badge .badge-key {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: #9b845a;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.badge .badge-value {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #232323;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="badge">
    <div class="badge-key">Condition</div>
    <div class="badge-value">Condition Text pulled from custom Product field</div>
  </div>
  <div class="badge">
    <div class="badge-key">Size</div>
    <div class="badge-value">Size Text pulled from custom Product field</div>
  </div>



